# Binding winform listview to dataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there any way to bind a winform ListView to a DataTable (or perhaps a list), in a similar manner in which it's done in a listview from visual web gui (in the last one, the listview has a dataSource property to do so)?

I know it can be done by, going through each of the table's elements and adding them to the ListView, but I would like to avoid using a foreach instrucction each time I have to fill a listview, or creating a method that recieve a listview as parameter and which fills the listview using a foreach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as ListView is concerned there is no direct way of setting its data source to a data table or similar. The only way is to iterate the data table or list and manually fill the items of ListView.

Comment: Do you know why did ms implemented that way? I mean, it's odd that a control in winform lacks some properties that, the exact same control has in web gui.

Comment: I am not sure why although I would love to know :) if you really have to bind it take a look at this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListView_DataBinding.aspx